# Remove Visited Sprite From Render Texture?

Tags: textures, cocos2d-x, render

Thanx in advance.
In cocos 2dx, I have a render texture and I want to remove its visited sprite one by one in reverse order in which it comes.Please tell me asap. If I use clear function , it removes all its visited sprite together, but i want to remove that visited sprite one by one.

Comment: you have to draw all sprites to the render texture again but with one less sprite

Answer (score -1):

I'd have to agree with @LearnCocos2D comment - what you want is not avaiable "out of the box". But rather then recreating your render texture every time you want to add/remove something, I'd consider using a `SpriteBatchNode` ( [docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2rc0/dd/d2f/classcocos2d_1_1_sprite_batch_node.html#details) ). You will be limited to only one texture/atlas file so you may need to create a spritesheet if you want to add different sprites to it, but it is really efficient when drawinng a lot of sprites. Also each sprite is added as a child to it, rather than "stamped" as with `RenderTexture`, which will give you full control of them in terms of adding/removing/animating/etc.